# why can't I execute code from an embedded file in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Good day to all time of day, there was such a problem:

in index.jsp passing the answer.jsp, here's the code:
index.jsp

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/graphic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="hero">
    <jsp:include page="jsps/hero.jsp"/>
</div>
<div class="graphic">
    <jsp:include page="jsps/graphic.jsp"/>
</div>
<div class="form-container">
    <jsp:include page="jsps/forms.jsp"/>
    <button id="checkButton">Проверить</button>
    <div id="outputContainer">
        <span class="outputStub notification">Результаты отсутствуют</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/checkboxHandler.js"></script>
<script src="js/formValidator.js"></script>
<script src="js/graphicValidator.js"></script>
<script src="js/session.js"></script>
<script src="js/table.js"></script>
</body>
```

answer.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>

<div class="table">
    <div class="table-header">
        <div>X</div>
        <div>Y</div>
        <div>R</div>
        <div>Входит ли в ОДЗ?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-content">
        <script>
            console.log("1111111111")
            AddInSession(${x}, ${y}, ${r}, ${result ? "<div style=\"color: green\">Да</div>" :
                            "<div style=\"color: red\">Нет</div>"})
        </script>
        <div class="table-row" id="table-row">
        </div>
        <script>Table()</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to pass values through the context and I did it, and I also need to return an answer.jsp, here is the code for one of the servlets

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    context.setAttribute("x", object.getX());
    context.setAttribute("y", object.getY());
    context.setAttribute("r", object.getR());
    context.setAttribute("result", object.getResult());
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsps/answer.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The browser sees the js code, but does not execute it. My concern is not so much that my methods are not being executed, but that console.log is also not producing results.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

P.S in index.jsp code is being executed

Comment: Not even console works? Did you check browser console?

Comment: @Swati, Yes, this is what confuses me, the code is simply ignored

Comment: @Swati, in this case, <div class="table-header" > in answer.jsp is being drawn

Comment: You mean `Table()` function gets executed? Can you check in browser console is there any error showing?

Comment: @Swati ,the browser console is empty, I really want to execute Table(), but I can't do it, but all html tags in answer.jsp (except script) are executed

Comment: @Swati ,I have the full code on github, if necessary

Comment: Okay add that as well in your question :)

Comment: @Swati, the question is no longer relevant, but I still wonder how it works